# Get index for closest value in array

Tags: ios, swift

Using the code from this answer to find the closest value in an array: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62159057

```
func closestMatch(values: [Int64], inputValue: Int64) -> Int64? {
   return (values.reduce(values[0]) { abs($0-inputValue) < abs($1-inputValue) ? $0 : $1 })
}
```

How can I get the index of the item that matches closest instead of its value?

Comment: Is the array sorted? That’s quite important.

Comment: @vadian Yes, the array is sorted from low to high.

Comment: Then have a look at `partitioningIndex(where:)` in [Swift Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Partition.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with `firstIndex`. Not super elegant but it works.

```
func closestMatch(values: [Int], inputValue: Int) -> Int? {
    let match = values.reduce(values[0]) { abs($0-inputValue) < abs($1-inputValue) ? $0 : $1 }
    let index = values.firstIndex(where: {$0 == match})
    return index
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the array is sorted, a fast solution would be to do a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Should be easy to modify [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51795188/1971013) (or others in the same post) to fit your purpose.